# How to prove that a linear transformation $T$ is one-to-one iff $\text{ker}\,T=\left\{0\right\}$?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I want to prove the statement below and I need you assistance.

```
Let T : V → W be linear transfomation , and W,V are vector spaces.
```

How do I prove that :

```
Transfomation T is one-to-one , if and only if , kerT = {0}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you rewritten the statement that $T$ is one-one in some different form, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

$\rightarrow $ if $T$ is one-to-one 
Proof by contradiction : Lets say $v \in Ker(T)$ and $v!=0$ then for any $w$, we have $Tw=T(w+v)$ which contradicts that T is one-to-one.
$\leftarrow$ if $kerT=\{0\}$
Proof by contradiction: Let say for $v!=w$, Tv=Tw then $v-w \in Ker(T)$ and $(v-w)!=0$ which contradicts that $ker(T)=\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $T$ is injective and note that $T(0)=0$. what does injectivity tell us about  the preimage of a single element?

Suppose that $\ker T=\{0\}$ and that $Tx=Ty$. then $Tx-Ty=0$. How can we use linearity to finish?